# Prove that $(-1)^n$ is bounded.

Tags: sequences-and-series

When proving the statement:

> Prove that $(-1)^n$ is bounded.

Is it enough to say since $\lvert (-1)^n\rvert = 1$, then $(-1)^n$ is bounded?

Or do I have to use induction to prove it?

Comment: Hint: If $n $ is even, then..., else, if $n $ is odd..., and you are done.

Comment: Yes, that's enough. Or observe that $-1\le(-1)^n\le 1$.

Comment: The question is impossible to answer, as it depends on the context.

Comment: @quid How's that, please? Can there be a context where that sequence isn't bounded?

Comment: @Joanpemo The question is **not** if the sequence is bounded, but if a certain argument is "enough". The answer to this depends on the context.

Comment: @quid Thank you. Then how the asker's argument can depend on context?

Comment: @Joanpemo the argument is correct, whether it is detailed enough depends on the context.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your definition of a sequence being bounded is that $a_n$ is bounded if $\operatorname{Range}(a_n)$ is a bounded set (there exists an $M$ such that $|a_n|\le M$ for all $n$).

Thus, showing that $\operatorname{Range}(a_n)=\{-1,1\}$ is enough.

Let $n$ be even, i.e, $n=2k$, then $(-1)^n=(-1)^{2k}=1^k=1$.

If $n$ is odd...

Comment: $|x^n|=|x|^n$…$ $

Comment: @egreg True :-p. Although I've changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the base case $n=0$, it is true that $ \left|(-1)^0\right|\le 42$.

Assume $\left|(-1)^n\right|\le 42$.

Consider $\left|(-1)^{n+1}\right|=|-1|\cdot\left|(-1)^n\right| \le 42$.

So $(-1)^n$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is enough, even if it is not required for $n$ to be an integer, when a standard power definition used